# Get Time and Date of a like on a Post with restfb

Tags: java, restfb

I am working on an application facebook and I use the API `restfb`.
I need to know :

1. the date of a `like` on a post.
2. who made this `like`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, share with us what you tried so far and any piece of code/documentation you think could help us.

Comment: FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient("accessToken");

Comment: Connection<Post> connection = facebookClient.fetchConnection("id of a facebook page"
    + "/feed", Post.class,Parameter.with("type", "post"),Parameter.with("limit",2));

Comment: Post post = connection.getData().get(0); //get the first post

Comment: JsonObject jsonObject = facebookClient.fetchObject(post.getId()+"/likes", JsonObject.class, Parameter.with("summary", true), Parameter.with("limit", 1));
  long likes = jsonObject.getJsonObject("summary").getLong("total_count");

Comment: PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  
  out.println("post message :" + post.getMessage()+"<br/>");
  out.println("likes count : " + likes+"<br/>");

Comment: for each like on this post, I want to know :
1 - the creation date.
2 - Who created this Like (user) .

Comment: Facebook don't provide the creation time of a like. So you won't be able to fetch this via restfb.